# javascript sort, Compare 3 different types and sort in order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, compare

I have an array of objects. each object has a "day type"; morning, afternoon, evening. They come in random order each time I get the list due to async differences... But I need to display them in following order: morning, afternoon, evening.

If I use array.sort() they will come out in order: afternoon, evening, morning. because it sorts alphabetically right?

So... I need a compare function. but I cant figure out how to make it since all examples I have found only has two input. sort(a, b)......

```
day.shifts = randomOrder;
day.shifts.sort((a, b, c) => {
    //some how compare all 3
}
```

I hope this is possible, and it is probably piece of cake.... Other wise I have thought of solutions like so

```
day.shifts = randomOrder;
const morning = [];
const afternoon = [];
const evening = [];

day.shifts.forEach(shift => {
    if(shift.type === 'morning'){
        morning.push(shift)
    }
    if(shift.type === 'afternoon'){
        afternoone.push(shift)
    }
    if(shift.type === 'evening'){
        evening.push(shift)
    }
}
day.shifts = morning.concat(afternoon).concat(evening);
```

I would prefer a compare method if that is possible. Or at least something a bit more "pretty" than my split to separate arrays and the concatenate method...

the objects in the list looks like this:

```
{
    type: 'morning',
    name: 'some person',
    id: 'person db index',
}
```

Comment: Well if you made your data structure better than variables, there would no need for an if statements.

Comment: Sort only compares two things and moves onto the next set, it is not something that loads every item at once.

Comment: I realised that.... Didn't think of it at first, when i quickly browsed through examples where i searched for "compare 3 values" i just assumed that the examples where simplified to compare two.... but now i know, its not about the "types" but about comparing two elements in the collection and deciding which one if first, no matter how many types there is in the order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort them like this:

```
 const order = ["morning", "afternoon", "evening"];

 day.shifts.sort((a, b) => order.indexOf(a.type) - order.indexOf(b.type));
```

That basically sorts the shifts after wich type comes first in the order array.

Answer (score 1):

You could sort by type with an object for the order.

```
var types = { morning: 1, afternoon: 2, evening: 3 };

day.shifts.sort((a, b) => types[a.type] - types[b.type]);
```